# Efficient Way To Compute Average Price

Tags: scala

I have the following function to compute the average price:

```
  def averagePrice(es: Stream[Order], t: Ric) = {
    val fes = es.filter(executions(_,t))
    if(fes.isEmpty) 0.0
    else fes.map(o => o.quantity * o.price).sum / fes.map(o => o.quantity).sum
  }
```

As you can see the `else` condition has to go through the stream twice: once to get the total cost and once to get the total volume. Is there a way to go through the stream once to compute the average price?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Iterate over stream and collect price and quantity at same time:

```
val (t, q) = fes.foldLeft((0,0)){
    (total, item) => (total._1 + item.quantity*item.price, total._2 + item.quantity)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can compute the average "on-the-fly"

```
def averagePrice(es: Stream[Order], t: Ric): Double =
  val fes = es.filter(executions(_, t))
  fes.foldLeft((0, 0.0)) { case ((i, avg), o) =>
    (i + 1, avg + (o.price * o.quantity - avg) / (i + 1))
  }._2
```